# calling specific DateTime date as an input argument, c#

Tags: c#, datetime

How do I use a specific date as an input value?

```
var experiment1 = WorkingWithDates.GetDisplayString("London", DateTime.Today, 45.00);
```

Later on, I'll be convering it to a string, but I need it to be input as a DateTime.

```
public static string GetDisplayString(string city, DateTime date, double temp)
{         
}
```

I'm using `DateTime.Today` as a placeholder, simply because it works. The thing is, I need it input as a specific day of a month of a year. (I've tried using (10, 10, 10) but it simply gives me a compiler error.

Edit.: I can't believe I did not figure out all I need to do is to add "new". Thanks folks

Comment: What "compiler error"? How exactly have you "tried using (10, 10, 10)"?

Comment: Did you try using the `new DateTime`overloads like `new DateTime(2013,10,10)`

Comment: What's the error you're getting? Also, `10,10,10` represents 10,10, or the year 0010 which, I'm guessing, isn't what you want.

Comment: Use constructor to build a new `DateTime` object,it's so basic...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `(10, 10, 10)` do you want the year `10`?

Use the constructor that takes in a year, a month and a day. As below.

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(2013, 12, 12);
```

then call your method

```
var experiment1 = WorkingWithDates.GetDisplayString("London", dt, 45.00);
```

PS: If you want year 10

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(10, 10, 10);
```

will work. The year will be `0010`

Answer (score 0):

```
WorkingWithDates.GetDisplayString("London", DateTime.Today, 45.00);
```

you need a `DateTime` object to be used in place of `DateTime.Today`, so construct your instance using

```
DateTime newdate = new DateTime(2013,10,10) // year, month , day
```

and then

```
WorkingWithDates.GetDisplayString("London", newdate, 45.00);
```